# Core Location geocoding from Google Places address does not work for Italian cities

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete, clgeocoder

I am using Google Places API for searching city names. In my view controller I am conforming to `GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate`:

```
func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didSelect prediction: GMSAutocompletePrediction) -> Bool {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(prediction.attributedFullText.string) { (placemark, error) in }
    return true
}
```

I need `CLGeocoder` in order to extract the `CLLocation` from the address string I am getting from Google Places API. This works perfectly for most cases except for Italian cities. Geocoder cannot handle the full address (example from Google Places result: *Roma, Metropolitan City of Rome, Italy*). What happens is you get a CLGeocoder error.

**What I tried**:

I tried only extracting the city + country names. This works for Italian cities but doesn't work for cities with the same name: New York, NY and New York, IA etc (you get wrong results).

Another solution would be to try with the `prediction.attributedFullText.string` and if it doesn't work retry with the above workaround.

Anyone's had the same issue or has an idea how to handle it more gracefully? I know it is kind of an edge case but I believe Google Places should've thought about the results working with CLGeocoder.

Comment: what exactly do you want? Do you want to convert the address to the location coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I need to get the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily get the `coordinates` and `formattedAddress` using the callback function.

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(String(describing: place.name))")
    print("Place address: \(String(describing: place.formattedAddress))")
    print("Place attributions: \(String(describing: place.attributions))")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    // get the selected coordinates and address like this
    let yourCordniates = place.coordinate
    let yourAddress = place.formattedAddress ?? ""


}
```

Comment: It's so obvious now. I didn't even test with this method because I thought it is called every time you type and not when you select a result. Thanks.